# Oracle drivers for Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, oracle

I created a sample dotnet core application. I use

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
```

to communicate with oracle database. Everything works fine on my machine.

But I am not familiar with Oracle ecosystem and don't know what should I install on my Windows Server 2016 machine. The application is hosted on IIS.

The Oracle Database is installed on separate Linux machine.

Comment: Do you have a separate database server hosting the Oracle database which your deployed application will access or you need to setup Oracle database on Windows server machine?

Comment: The databes is being served on separate linux machine.

Comment: Ok so as far as your database server is accessible from the Windows server you can publish your .NET Core application there. Are you not sure about the steps for hosting .NET Core application on Windows server and IIS?

Comment: Exactly. I'd like to ask for set of drivers needed to properly host dot net core application in IIS server.

Comment: For oracle database connectivity you already have added reference to `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`. For publishing the .NET Core application on IIS you can follow instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: So, don't I need any addidional drivers on my Windows Server machine?

Comment: I don't think so. You will have a connectionstring pointing at your Oracle database server and `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` will help your app connect to the database using the connectionstring

Comment: You don't need to install anything. Just provide file `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` with your application, that's it.